# Enabling remote connections to IIS 7.x Management Service by using Powershell

Tags: iis, iis-7, powershell, iis-7.5

Is it possible to execute the "Enable Remote Connections" step from this [instructions](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/) ("Remote Administration for IIS Manager") using Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this page on [IIS Remote Mgmt](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/334/install-and-configure-iis-on-server-core/), it appears you will need to add a registry key:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server /v EnableRemoteManagement /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

To add a new regkey wiht powershell, try:

```
New-Item -path Registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server\EnableRemoteManagement -PropertyType DWord -Value 1
```

Please note this is not tested.

Comment: I would like to avoid changing the registry "directly" but if that's the only option, well, that will be.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev - I will vouch for this answer, this is the only way to configure that setting.

Comment: @Milen - time to live on the edge :-)

Answer (score 0):

The above PowerShell command may not work for you. Try this instead:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1
```